# Function/Object's to shorten code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to shorten some of my code that has different ways of replacing specific patterns that I've set. Basically this code replaces the HTML that I've set as: `<span class="combination">0000-AAAA-0000-BBBB</span>`

```
function randomised(len) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
}

function randomiseStrings(str){
    var alphSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var numSet = "0123456789";
    var alphNumSet = alphSet.concat(numSet);

    // 1) Replace 0 with random number.
    var str = str.replace(/0/g, function() {
        return numSet[randomised(numSet.length)];
    });

    // 2) Replace A with random number or letter.
    var str = str.replace(/A/g, function() {
        return alphNumSet[randomised(alphNumSet.length)].toUpperCase();
    });

    // 3) Replace B with random letter.
    var str = str.replace(/B/g, function() {
        return alphSet[randomised(alphSet.length)].toUpperCase();
    });

    return str;
}

$('.combination').text(function(i,t){
    return randomiseStrings(t);
});
```

So as you can see I got 3 identical scripts. However I just couldn't figure out how to do it. What I'm aiming to do is be able to to change these values: `str.replace(/[A]/g,`, `a = alphSet/numSet/alphNumSet` and possability to add: `.toUpperCase();`.

The problem I ended up with what I have no clue how to return these values if I make it as a function. For any suggestion or idea I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Tip `/[0]/ == /0/` and `/[A]/ == /A/`, etc. You don't need character sets for just one character.

Comment: You can just use `return  numSet[randomised(numSet.length)];` instead of creating a variable. Also define `str` only once, not three times. Unless you are going to add much more similiar functions, I would leave it as it is now. Alternative solutions using a generic function won't be as clear as it is now.

Comment: @Christphe, I'm trying to make more "scalable" script just to learn different techniques. So having the option to make custom patterns such as row 3 of the serial code is only numbers 0-2 and letters A,B,C. So for example 0000-0000-0A2C. I just think it's somewhat fun way for me to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few places fat can be cut here. First I would go ahead and capitalize all of alphSet so that you don't have to call toUpperCase(). alphNumSet is made up of 2 strings, you can just use string concatenation to combine them rather than the concat function. The function your looking for would just be a matter of factoring out the difference between the calls you're sending.

```
    function randomised(len) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    }

    function getRandom(str, regEx, set){
        return str.replace(regEx, function() {
            return set[randomised(set.length)];
        });
    }

    function randomiseStrings(str){
        var alphSet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        var numSet = "0123456789";
        var alphNumSet = alphSet + numSet;

        str = getRandom(str, /0/g, numSet);
        str = getRandom(str, /A/g, alphNumSet)
        str = getRandom(str, /B/g, alphSet)

        return str;
    }

    $('.combination').text(function(i,t){
        return randomiseStrings(t);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You already took the first step and identified repeating parts of your code. All you have to do now is to create a function using those parts as parameters.

```
function replaceWithRandom(text, regex, randomSet) {
  return text.replace(regex, function() {
    return randomSet[randomised(randomSet.length)].toUpperCase();
  });
}

str = replaceWithRandom(str, /0/g, numSet);
str = replaceWithRandom(str, /A/g, alphSet);
str = replaceWithRandom(str, /B/g, alphNumSet);
```

`numSet` contains only strings, so calling `toUpperCase` is superfluous but won't cause any issues.